# Elements of dynamically allocated array don't use -> operator after first element?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a tutorial on C++ that demonstrates how to call an object's public methods from an element of an array using the subscript syntax. It goes something like this:

```
Foo* array = new Foo[2];

array->public_function();

array[1].public_function();
```

Now I understand that the variable `array` points to the first element of the array and thus uses the `->` operator to access that element's public data and functions. My question is, why would the call to the `array[1]` be any different - why would it use the `.` syntax as opposed to the `->` syntax? Aren't all elements of the array pointers?

Comment: No, they're `Foo`s. If they were pointers, you'd need something like `(*array)->public_function` in the first line.

Comment: `array->` means `array[0].`   `(array+1)->` means `array[1].` Etc

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers! Man, C++ is so dense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you use the indexing `[]`, you get the object, not the pointer to the object.

Consider the following example, which works with the pointer directly by using pointer arithmetic.

```
Foo* array = new Foo[2];

// Following four are equivalent.   
array[0].public_function();
array->public_function();
(array + 0)->public_function();
(&array[0])->public_function();

// Following three are equivalent.
array[1].public_function();
(array + 1)->public_function();
(&array[1])->public_function();
```

Comment: Also `(&array[0])->public_function();` and `(&array[1])->public_function();`

Comment: There are three kinds of people editing answers on StackOverflow: those who can count, and those who can't  ;) @Jherico

Comment: @MooseBoys: Right, and let's not forget `(*array).public_function()`

Comment: @MooseBoys, I added some more.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as if the `[]` operator returns a reference to `Foo`, so you use the `.` operator to access its members.

Answer (score 1):

`array->public_function()` is the same as `(*array).public_function()` which is the same as `array[0].public_function()`.  You are accessing `public_function()` through a raw pointer to a `Foo` object instance. The compiler has no concept that the pointer is actually an array of `Foo` instances.  Like you said, `array` is just a pointer to the first element in the array.  All of the above syntaxes are valid on **any** object pointer.  Since you are dealing with an array, you should stick with the `array[0].public_function()` syntax for consistency and readibility.